# Where is Google Play icon used?

Tags: android, icons, google-play

I read that there must be a Google Play icon which has to be 512x512 pixel for deploying my app at Google Play:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#icons_in_market.

But when I browse through the market, I've never seen such an icon with these dimensions. Where is actually this used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 512x512 icon is in the lower left corner in the left panel. That's all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

That icon is used in High-res icon ( 512 x 512) . It shows on web Google Play.

Comment: There is a small icon below the app name (124x124) and a big header (705x344). Is it the small icon which is maybe downsized?

Comment: @Bevor Please refer this link . https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870 and check High Resolution Application Icon (Required):

Comment: "Use: In various locations in Google Play", I already read that, but I don't see any icon of these size (I looked for Tetris for example).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the store on the web, and possibly on tablets and other high-rez views, especially in the "featured items" panels.

Answer (score 0):

It's the one that is visible everywhere on the web (search results,...) and in a bigger size on the page of an application.

Comment: I know there is a big picture on every app but this picture is not 512x512.